# How to access cutom listview with checkbox in dialog Android?

Tags: android, listview, dialog, alert

I had a custom listview with checkbox in alert dialog. I want to access the row with selected checkbox on Done button click. Here is the screen short of the image.

Here I'm using hash map both arguments string with custom list

Thanks in Advance[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way could be set a listener to your CheckBoxes and add/remove the row (object, view or whatever you need) to a list when the check changes.

Another way to achieve this could be to iterate over your rows and see if the CheckButton is checked or not. But this choice won't be good in performance if you have too many rows.

Comment: i had used Layout Inflator in which I had two Text view and one check box. So check box listener can not be implemented.

Comment: Even if you just create a CheckBox instance (via new) or inflating it, you could always get that view and add a listener. Put a sample code in your post if you want so I can help you to fix that.